# How many different numbers from $1,2,7,8$ taking one,two,three and four digits no repetitions and how many of them are above $200$?

Tags: permutations

Taking one, two, three and four digits from digits $1,2,7$ and $8$, and if repetitions are not allowed

1. How many different numbers can be arranged?
2. How many of them would be greater than $200$?

I got the first answer $= 64$:

- $4$ one digit numbers
- $12$ two digit numbers
- $24$ three digit numbers
- $24$ four digit numbers

total $= 64$

How to know how many are above $200$ though?

Comment: Hint. Assuming your counts are correct so far (I haven't checked) - what fraction of the three digit numbers are greater than 200? What about the one, two and four digit numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations for the firs question are correct. For the second, any $4$ digit number is $>200$ and any three digit number that starts with $2,7$ or $8$. Hence, $3$ out of $4$ three digit numbers are above $200$, which gives you a total of $$24+\frac{3}{4}24=42$$ numbers above 200.

Comment: Correct and nicely said, so upvoted. That said I'd rather you'd waited a while so the OP could try for him or herself with the hint, and maybe learn a little more.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, and ... thanks, you are right, I will keep that in mind.